# Get value of dict key without iterating items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict where the keys are of a class type. The `__eq__` method of this class is implemented such that some of the class elements are ignored during comparison:

```
class ID:
    def __init__(self, name, location):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
```

I use the dict to find elements of this class, no matter what the value of the `location` element is:

```
types = {ID("foo", "<stdin>:2:5"): "some data", ID("bar", "<stdin>:10:5"): "other data"}
search = ID("foo", "<stdin>:11:5")
if search in types:
    print(f"duplicate entry {search.name}")
```

However, when I want the `location` value of the key *stored in the dict*, I need to iterate through the dict:

```
if search in types:
    print(f"duplicate entry {search.name}")
    r = [k for k, _ in types.items() if k == search][0]
    print(f"previous location: {r.location}")
```

Is there any better way to obtain the key object of a dict from another key (which is considered equal)?

Edit: I'm interested in Python 3 only.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the key object as part of the values:

```
# store the value and key as a tuple 
lookup_types = {k: (k, v) for k, v in types.items()}
if search in lookup_types:
    print(f"duplicate entry {search.name}")
    r, _ = lookup_types[search]
    print(f"previous location: {r.location}")
```

**Output**

```
duplicate entry foo
previous location: <stdin>:2:5
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the natural solution. Unfortunately, I'd need to change a lot of existing code for this. Hence I was hoping to get the original key out of the dict directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to directly get the attribute with this piece of code ?

```
search.location
```

or

```
types[search].location
```

This will give you the value you are looking for.

Comment: Note that they want the location *of the key*, not of the value. ``search`` is the search key and ``types[search]`` is the associated value – neither have the location of the actual key.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict sub class that will find the duplicate key for you

```
class ID:
    def __init__(self, name, location):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

class MyDict(dict):
  def getSimilarKey(self, key):
    for k in self.keys():
      if k == key:
        return k
    return None
  @classmethod
  def create(cls, d):
    tmp = cls()
    tmp.update(d)
    return tmp

types = MyDict.create({ID("foo", "<stdin>:2:5"): "some data", ID("bar", "<stdin>:10:5"): "other data"})
search = ID("foo", "<stdin>:11:5")
if search in types:
    print(f"duplicate entry {search.name}")
    print(f"previous location: {types.getSimilarKey(search).location}")
```